# does one need any 'programming aptitude' to become a web-designer?

Tags: html, css

It's well-known among teachers that some people can program and some can't. They just don't have mindset for that. In a nut-shell, I want to ask if the same is true about web-design.

I have a friend who is a good designer in general and can produce reasonably good-looking sites with WYSIWYG editor like Dreamweaver. But, since we're starting a common project, I'd like someone who can 'get hands dirty': work with html and css code directly. For many reasons, I'm sure you understand.
Now I'm thinking to incite him to learn, but not sure what're the chances of success.

So, do you also need some 'programming abilities' to profess css and html, or it's just a matter of training for regular designer?

I would especially like to hear particular experience from web designers.

PS I intentionally leave out JavaScript, let's keep it simple

Comment: You can design a website without any knowledge of HTML/CSS in a WYSIWYG. That's it though that will be all it can do. Be the layout and text. Essentially

Comment: @Ozaki only very simple website. It's like saying "you can program everything in Excel, no need for C++" Of course, you can :)

Comment: Nope. It has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best web **designers** I have worked with know a small amount of html but don't use it when they are designing the sites. They do their work in PhotoShop (a minority will use GIMP). The reality is that I would rather they concentrate on laying out eye catching websites instead of trying to code it and lay the site out on the fly.

A web designer is absolutely not the same person as a front end web developer. That person has a skillset aimed towards converting the designers work into a set of working html/css templates.

Let me be clear that I am not saying that there is no cross-over between the two skillsets, but rather that very few people will be excellent at both design and development. If you are willing to settle for less than stellar results, at least be sure you go into the project with your eyes open.

Comment: If designers doesn't work with code, who converts storyboard images to html? The majority of front-end developers (me including) have very limited artistic abilities.

Comment: But I get what you're trying to say: generating html/css is a programming (development), not design work.

Comment: Front end web developers would do that conversion. The designer if necessary will produce the flattened image pieces as necessary. If the developer doesn't familiarity with the program the designer used to build the design it will be far faster this way (and with better results many times)

Comment: If you're paying a "designer" to do photoshop, and a "front end web developer" to lay out a site's CSS for you, they're both only doing half a job.  I've never worked with designers who didn't do their own layout conversions.  Markup and CSS doesn't have much to do with coding anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Not at all. HTML is not a programming language, it's a markup language.
It shouldn't take you long to figure it out; I did it when I was 12. I personally think you need to be a better, how do I put it... artist to design websites than a programmer.

Of course websites nowadays are a lot more interactive, and for that you'll need some sort of server scripting (PHP, ASP, etc) and Javascript - and these are real programming languages.

Comment: Of course, it helps to know what constructs in HTML lean themselves towards programmability. Dumping a ton of divs into each other to build a table is going to give the eventual programmer gray hair before he's even started.

Answer (score 3):

A web designer who can't hand code HTML/CSS is not a web designer. The lack of such skills shows more of an aptitude problem(wanting to improve one's self). the graphic designer + front end developer combo doesn't always work well, because chances are the developer doesn't have the eye for the details in the design, such as margin, line-height, text kerning etc etc. Also it's hard to convert the interactive elements as well.

edit: this topic has been debated within the web design community on and off for a while now. You may find some interesting links in the [blog post](http://www.8164.org/web-designers-coding/) I wrote regarding this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting link! +1

Answer (score 2):

you are much better to know how to code a website HTML / CSS / Javascript before you go saying your amazing with a WYSIWYG editor. Sure you can use software to create a nice looking site but when it comes down to it how do you solve cross browser issues? How do you add dynamic content (even without server side) a WYSIWYG editor is just like designing a website in powerpoint or word but a lot more smarts. Though without the backing knowledge you are not going to go far.

As for learning plain HTML / CSS is fairly simple its an easy markup to get the understanding of. But then with that comes more, learning how to SEO plain HTML for example. There is always more to a site than HTML / CSS for it to be successfull.

Comment: 100% dependant on what the site needs if its plain HTML / CSS then not much is required but that is as far as you will get it.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a life question; I suspect it is true about almost anything. I think it can be hard to guage someone's aptitude for programming without seeing them actually try to program for awhile, however. Many people need to struggle with it for awhile before an "AHA!" moment is reached.

Nevertheless, I don't think design skills and abaility to work with CSS and HTML necessarily correlate to an aptitude for programming, per se. Of course, the two are not mutually exclusive,

Answer (score 1):

It is not important for the designer to be able to program/markup/code in HTML or CSS. However, it is important for the designer to be **aware** of the current constraints imposed by HTML/CSS. With things becoming more dynamic, it is also important for the designer to understand how things are going to interact with each other. For example, you cannot become a real architect, without being aware of the constraints imposed by civil engineering.

But that's it. It is not important for a good designer to even know Dreamweaver or Photoshop or some other software :)

Comment: That's an interesting point, thanks! I guess, I'll have to learn to convert images to html/css myself, then :)

Comment: No no, the designer, because he is understands the html/css constraints, should be able to supply you with images, that can be easily used to implement the design. For example, if you are designing a tabbed interface, the designer should be able to give you the background images for the tab states, with proper sizes and without some text embedded in them. You should just have to reference the images in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I am a university teacher, and I have also written both computer programs and HTML.  Although I teach math, I understand the point about teaching computer programming.  Although it might seem like there is no gray area between being able to program and not, I would say that writing in a markup language is one.  You shouldn't divide the world into "cans" and "can'ts" with a question like this.

If he's a generally bright guy, yes you should encourage him to learn HTML and CSS.  I wouldn't propagandize it as the thing that real men do or the greatest thing since sliced bread.  Rather my argument would be to have a more complete perspective of what, after all, he's already been doing.  Just as a racecar driver shouldn't necessarily need to pick up a wrench, but knowing what to do with one is useful for a deeper understanding.   If you offer your friend a positive sell, the worst that can happen is that he'll say no and not take your advice.  And who knows, he might even like it.

A lot of people either can't program or just wouldn't enjoy it, but don't mind writing in markup all that much.  Most research mathematicians these days write their papers directly in a markup language, TeX/LaTeX, that in some ways looks a lot like HTML.  Some mathematicians also like to write computer programs, but most of them don't.  If they did like it, there is a good chance that they would have ended up in Silicon Valley.  In fact in my profession, the whole question of can or can't write markup, or can or can't write programs, is stale.  We're long used to a continuous range of abilities.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you can't have enough knowledge about this sort of stuff when doing any type of computer design or software implementation.

The more you know about the underlying technology, the better you will be at working with the high-level frameworks and constraints you live in.

Even if you work only in Photoshop in order to design a website, having the knowledge about what works and what will be more difficult in HTML/CSS/Whatever will give you an edge when designing that website over someone who doesn't know those details.

Of course, with knowledge comes constraints, which might be bad in and of themselves. Some of the best new technologies out there was built by people who didn't know that almost everyone else thought that what they tried to do was impossible.

But I still hold that more knowledge = Good Thing™

Answer (score 0):

Web site creation especially a commercial website involves a LOT of different skill sets.

Back-end requires:

System Administration, Database Administration,

Web Applications development (anytime a website becomes interactive) requires server side programming skills and knowing various tools like (PHP, Java, ASP, Perl, C, C#, pick-flavour-of-the-month-server-side-language) and client side programming requires knowledge of browser behaviours mark-up languages and browser-side layout systems (HTML, javascript, CSS...)

Web Design requires artistic visual skills and related tools (Graphics programs)

Web Content requires language skills (Knowing how to proof read, translate, etc.).

Site Optimization requires knowledge of how to make sites appeal to various readers and audiences (both human and robotic)

A professional website involves several folks working in-tandem to bring all of the above together in various quantities.

If you are going to pursue something as a career, you need to know a bit about all aspects of that space and then follow in on what really excites you. So if someone is good at creating visually appealing content they should simply plan the content, and collaborate with someone to "program" their vision into the site.

Learning tools, and knowing about various components, is good as it tells you the boundaries and the playing field scope, but you don't need to know all of it to achieve professional competence in one specialization.